# Effect of mutually dependent targets in Xcode 4?

Tags: build, xcode4, target

In my project, I have my main target (The one with all my product code).
Halfway through the project I created another target to hold unit tests.

I have made my main target dependent on the unit tests target, so that whenever I build my project, I run the unit tests automatically.

Should my unit tests target also be dependent on my main target? (Currently I have set it as dependent).

What is the effect of each target being dependent on each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should my unit tests target also be dependent on my main target?

no. that's a circular dependency.